# How should we tag Tony Hawk's Pro Skater 1+2?

Tags: discussion, tags

**Once again publishers are conspiring against us with titles that don't make easy tags**

In this particular case, we're limited by what characters are allowed to be in tags. [tony-hawks-pro-skater-1+2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tony-hawks-pro-skater-1%2b2) doesn't work, neither does [tag:tony-hawks-pro-skater-1&2], and [tony-hawks-pro-skater-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tony-hawks-pro-skater-hd) is already a remake from 2012.

How should we tag this slightly odd title while making sure that we can be clear about which game we are talking about?

Comment: Interestingly, 1+2 does work in a posted meta question, but didn't work in the preview (and doesn't work in the tag box for a question I already tried)

Comment: but if you click through, it appears to be 2 tags

Comment: @MBraedley Which is consistent with what it does in the tag box so I guess that makes sense

Comment: it's weird that the tag box won't accept '1+2', but [tags ending in + are fine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth%2b)

Comment: @Robotnik I guess that makes sense given that, for example, [c++] very much needed to be allowed over on SO

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm leaning towards [tony-hawks-pro-skater-1-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tony-hawks-pro-skater-1-2) with [tony-hawks-pro-skater-2020](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tony-hawks-pro-skater-2020) as a synonym.

The name is awkward but I think that's the best we can do, short of the tag system changing.

Answer (score 0):

How about something basic? When in doubt, just add the relevant year

[tony-hawks-pro-skater-1-2-2020](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tony-hawks-pro-skater-1-2-2020)

Comment: Personally I think that both -1-2 and -2020 aren't too necessary together, one or the other would probably be fine

Comment: 1-2-2020 looks like a date (first of february or second january? :))